# Scala's `toMap` in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scala

Is there any idiomatic javascript solution for this one:

```
var addTuple = function(map,tuple) { map[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]; return map}
```

I need it to rewrite [this example (see finance3.js)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#service) in more functional style:

```
angular.module('finance3', [])
.factory('currencyConverter', ['$http', function($http) {
      var rates = {}; //should be future (or some other monad) mapped from $http.sucess, but it's hard to do with Js
      var processRate = function(rate) {
          return [rate.id.substring(3,6),  window.parseFloat(rate.Rate)];
      };
      var addTuple = function(map,tuple) { map[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]; return map};
      $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {     
          rates = data.query.results.rate.map(processRate).reduce(addTuple, {});
      });  
     return rates
}]);
```

So, `.reduce(addTuple, {})` is like `toMap` here.

P.S. By the way [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) provides at least more reactive (but still non-pure functional) way to update the model.

Comment: http://ramdajs.com/docs/#fromPairs might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use an external library, [lodash](https://lodash.com) has [`_.pairs`](https://lodash.com/docs#pairs) and [`_.zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject) to transform objects into arrays of two-dimensional arrays (that is, `{key: value}` to `[[key: value]]`) and viceversa.

```
var x = _.pairs({ 'barney': 36, 'fred': 40 });
// [['barney', 36], ['fred', 40]]

var y = _.zipObject(x)
// { 'fred': 30, 'barney': 40 }
```

You can rewrite your example as

```
rates = _.zipObject(data.query.results.rate.map(processRate))
```

Comment: @dk14 From the doc: *Provide either a single two dimensional array, e.g. [[key1, value1], [key2, value2]] or two arrays, one of property names and one of corresponding values.*

In other words, if you do `_.zipObject([['barney', 36], ['fred', 40]]);` it works as expected (as shown in the example)

Comment: single array, right :), Thanks. The example from docs was little confusing for me